# c++ template class error when referencing implementation of class from inside the header file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates

Edit: I fixed it after restarting everything from scratch. I'm not sure what caused the issue. If anyone has any idea, or insight what was causing the main issue, I'll edit the first post with the follow up.

so I'm doing a homework assignment to create a heap class that utilizes a template to be able to use both numerical data, and strings. The compiler I'm using is visual studio 2010

The header file looks like this..

```
#ifndef HEAP_H
#define HEAP_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>       // not needed if you use a static array

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;
template <typename type>
class Heap {
... the method headers I have to implement in the Heap.template file
};
#include "Heap.template"

#endif
```

The Heap.template file is where we're supposed to implement the methods of the heap. However, I cannot compile without being slaughtered by errors. Here's the first method supplied by the instructor himself:

```
template <typename type>
Heap<type>::Heap(bool maxheap) {
// this default constructor supports a dynamic array. In this array, the root
// of the heap begins at index 1; the variable "dummy" is used to fill the 
// zero position of the dynamic array.  
type dummy;
  this->maxheap = maxheap;
  heap.push_back(dummy);
  size = heap.size()-1;
}
```

Even if I comment out the rest of the methods that I've implemented, I'm still presented with the errors

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-     int
error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
error C2059: syntax error : '<'
```

on line the

```
Heap<type>::Heap(bool maxheap) {
```

These same set of errors exist for every single method I try to implement in the supplied .template file, for instance this print method

```
template <typename type>
void Heap<type>::PrintHeap()
{
for( std::vector<type>::iterator i = heap.begin(); i != heap.end(); ++i)
{
    cout << *i << ' ';
}
}
```

Gives me the same set of errors as his supplied methods. I'm really perplexed at the moment, and really have no idea what's causing the issue. I'd appreciate some insight, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should not include `<type>` on your class when you are defining the member functions.  Do this:

```
template <typename type>
Heap::Heap(bool maxheap) {
    //...
}
```

The compiler already knows the class uses those template parameters because of the `template` statement.

Comment: Well, I tried this and it didn't solve the issue. I restarted everything from scratch, created a new empty project, redownloaded the files, and the error is no longer there. So I'm really not sure what I did to cause it.

It may also be worth noting that in my Heap.template, if I omit the <type> in my member functions, it actually gives me an error, and only compiles if I follow the format Heap<type>::Function().